# answer Vehicle database design - Type, Make, Model, Vehicle

Tags: mysql

I kindly ask you for advice, if I am correct with my DB design. I am writing an app in Django (it has its own ORM), which will use SQL SERVER 2019. My expectation is, that I will specify:

Type (example: Automobile, Motorcycle, Boat, ...)
Make (example: Honda, BMW, Audi, ...)
Model (example: CBR1000, A6, A8, 535i, ...)
Vehicle - all other info, like VIN, price, ...
So I think that the best way is to have Makes unique. I don't know, what to do with a Type. I think that the best way is to have a foreign key of a Type in a Model - because for example Honda can produce Automobiles and also Motorcycles. So by Model we can found, what vehicle type is it.

I want to make a web form filter (some kind of three linked dropdowns), where the user will select a Type, then it will filter out all Makes for that selected type. Then in another dropdown, he will select a Make and in the third dropdown, there will be shown all Models, which is available in that selection. Something like a Copart has - Vehicle Finder on the right side of web page https://www.bastrucks.com/

Comment: *I think that the best way is to have a foreign key of a Type in a Model - because for example Honda can produce Automobiles and also Motorcycles.* What depends on what? Dealer on Type? Type On Dealer?  none on none! So these are two independent M:N related entities. Dealer table (Honda, BMW, ...), Type table (Automobile, Motorcycle, ...), junction table. A Model (CBR1000, A6, ...) refers to this junction table.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, tag it so.  Do not ask MySQL users.

Answer (score 1):

Make + Type is a 2-column table of who makes what type of vehicle.

Models apply (usually) to a single Make+Type combo.  Simply have a 3-column table.

The above lists indicate what is manufactured, not that you have any Vehicles of the combination given.  The above lists are used for your pulldowns.

There is very little use in 'normalizing' any of the values mentioned above; simply use the strings in question.

The Vehicle table, on the other hand, has lots of strings and a few numbers (model_year, engine displacement, etc).  It *could* have a simple id into the table with Make+Type+Model in order to offload those 3 things.

I recommend you set up a database with something like the above; then write the `SELECTs` that you need.  Finally re-assess the schema and possibly tweak it.